# How to format phone number while typing in angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to let the user simply type
`1234567890` and the entry change to `123 456 7890`. The formatting should take effect while typing and not on focus or blur. Any thought?

Comment: Check this [link](https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/tree/master/angular2).

Comment: Thanks. That's what I needed!

Comment: one hour into your suggestion solution and can't pass this error: Can't bind to 'textMask' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. Any thought how to solve that?

Comment: Did you follow every configuration step on Readme?